# How can I connect to smb share after connecting to VPN?

Tags: mount, samba, vpn, nas, smb

I'm new to Ubuntu and networking and I've got myself stuck.

I have an budget NAS setup (raspberry pi running OMV with an SMB share). I have setup the share in Ubuntu by following [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) guide. I have permanently mounted the drive and can access all the files in the share. However, after connecting to a VPN (surfshark), following [this](https://support.surfshark.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017418334-How-to-set-up-Surfshark-VPN-on-Linux-) guide I can no longer access the share. I get the following message "Could not display "share". The file is of unknown type".

Setting up the VPN entailed editing /etc/fstab, and putting this:

```
//my.nas.ip.address/media  /media/share  cifs  credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

Would I need to change this to access the NAS?

Also, when I run the VPN on my windows machine, I don't have any trouble accessing the NAS.

edit:

I should also mention that I'm running Ubuntu through a VM on the windows machine

Comment: I had seen this question previously, but i'm unsure what a subnet is. I'll do some research as that question probably does answer my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Which virtualization product are you using, Virtualbox?

If so, I'm guessing you're using the "NAT" networking type which sets up a mini-LAN on your local computer in the 192.168.56.0/24 range (by default).  Your NAS is probably on your "real" LAN which has a different IP range.  This becomes an issue because the VPN puts a default route rule that basically says "send anything not in my local LAN (192.168.56.0/24) over the VPN" which then routes your NAS-destined traffic over the VPN.

There are two solutions, assuming my guesses above are correct:

1. Switch the Virtualbox NIC type to "bridged" which assigns your VM an IP directly on your "real" LAN.  This is fine for most use-cases but may not be what you want.
2. Create a a custom route in your VM that sends your "real" LAN traffic to the mini-LAN gateway (192.168.56.1 by default in Virtualbox)

Comment: I'm using Hyper-V. I'm not sure how I would do either of those suggestion. Sorry, I have no idea about networking